# SQL2008. What is URL for SSRS webservice?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting, ssrs-2008

I have working SSRS but am trying to access it from C# code using SSRS **webservice**. From what I know it should be something like http://server/Reports/ReportExecution2005.asmx for SQL2005 if install was with default values.

How do you test if your SSRS 2008 **webservice** up and running and / or accessible (ie not bloced by firewall)? What the URL look like ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at below. Depends on if it is named instance or default instance.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677364.aspx#DefaultURLs

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630447.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use Reporting Services Configuration Manager (Either locally on the SSRS server or from a remote machine that has the Configuration Manager installed from SQL Server media) to check what base URL is used by the web service, the default is http://server/ReportServer/ if you can browse that URL with your browser the firewall is open and you should be able to connect to the webservice interfaces http://server/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx or ReportService2005.asmx

These MSDN articles contains more examples:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154052%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152787%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx

Comment: thanks. can you tell what would be the reason that I cant detect webservice but the web UI is working fine? BTW - the box doesnt have IIS installed but I presume that SSRS 2008 should be fine without it... Is it possbile the webservice was not installed?